# Server Local Administrators are Farm Administrator is required?

Tags: 2013, security

when we create new farm the server local administrators accounts users are farm administrators as BuilIN\Administrators

-When i check local administrators there is Domain/Domain Admins 
Is if we remove this BuilIN\Administrators there is any risk to the sharepoint farm?

Is this required by sharepoint farm functionality or if we remove it is there any issues ?

Answer (score 1):

When you install (or upgrade) SharePoint on a server, the SP_Install account have to be a local administrator on the server. Preferably in the group Local Admins. When install (or upgrade) is finished, you can safely remove SP_Install from the local admin group.

Answer (score 1):

As per my experience, you need a service account in local admin on sharepoint servers, in order to do daily maintenance, powershell execution, applying patches etc

As my experience, we have farm admin always in the local admin account.

Many best practices recommended have a separate account for installation and dedicated account for farm admin.
Once installation complete then remove the install account from local admin

Comment: yes domain admins also farm admins , if we remove builtin\administrators there is any issue to the farm?

Comment: If you add other accounts directly in the farms dmin group then you can remove it